# jQuery download image from external source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a link such as:

```
http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/c/c1/3rd_age_amulet.png/revision/latest?cb=20141217224859
```

and I want to download this into a specific folder with a specific name with jQuery/javascript.

Are there any solutions to this? I can't find anything that even references it - I wouldn't know where to begin with this, as it's the first time I've attempted something like this.

If someone could point me in the right direction?

I currently have a list of images loaded into the page from external resource:

num.txt

```
3rd age amulet
3rd age full helmet
3rd age kiteshield
3rd age mage hat
3rd age platebody
3rd age platelegs
3rd age range coif
3rd age range legs
3rd age range top
3rd age robe top
3rd age robe
3rd age vambraces
3rd age longsword
3rd age bow
3rd age wand
3rd age cloak
```

dumper.php

```
$file = "num.txt";
$focus = "https://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/";
foreach(file("../resources/items/names/$file") as $line) {
    $item_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $line);
    $url = $focus . $item_name;
    $fc = file_get_contents($url);
    echo get_between("<td colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align: center;\">", "Release date", $fc);
}

function get_between($start, $end, $subject) {
    $temp1 = strpos($subject, $start) + strlen($start);
    $result = substr($subject, $temp1, strlen($subject));
    $dd = strpos($result, $end);
    if($dd == 0) {
        $dd = strlen($result);
    }
    return substr($result, 0, $dd);
}
```

tl;dr: I now have a bunch of images loaded onto my page, I can access each of them with jQuery:

```
<script>
$("img").each(function() {
    console.log(this.src);
})
</script>
```

I want to download each of these into a folder with a specific filename.

Comment: Javascript is client side. It cannot force the browser to automaticly start downloading data to the users harddrive. This would be a violation of privacy and security.

Comment: You can take a look at the File API to read the file and store it in the localStorage (post: http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html) but @icecub already pointed that you cannot do that.

Comment: @icecub, don't want this for my users, I want it for my server. Although it would make more sense to pass this data back to PHP and download it with that, I guess?

Comment: i.e. there's a lot of data/images I need to store and I'm too lazy to do them individually so I'm trying to automate it.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle So, you want to save the images in folder on your server, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a zip file from images and download it (by js).